# PHP: How to delete rows from an associative array

Tags: php, loops, associative-array

I have an associative array, where the keys are datetime  type data (with an interval of 15 minutes)

```
    array:37 [▼
      "09:00" => Appointment {
                    #attributes: array:10 [▼
                        "id" => 1135
                        "startDateTime" => "2019-11-19 09:00:00"
                        "endDateTime" => "2019-11-19 09:45:00"
                        "duration" => 45
                    ]
                  }
      "09:15" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 15 minutes
      "09:30" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 30 minutes  end of the appointment
      "09:45" => ""
      "10:00" => Appointment {...duration => 60 ...}
      "10:15" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 15 minutes
      "10:30" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 30 minutes
      "10:45" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 45 minutes
      "11:00" => ""     // I want to delete this row -> 60 minutes end of the appointment
      "11:15" => ""
      "11:30" => ""
      "11:45" => "" Appointment {...duration => 15 ...}
       ...
    ]
```

This array will feed a table, so I want to delete the subsequent rows based on the duration of each appointment. I need it because i want to span the appointment over several rows with:

```
<td class="the-appointment" rowspan="{{ $appointment->duration / 15 }}">...
```

therefore I need to eliminate the subsequent rows from the array.

I did this:

```
    $index = -1;
    foreach ($row as  $key => $appointment) {
        if ($appointment) {
            $loops = $appointment->duration / 15;
        }
        for ($i = 1; $i < $loops; $i++) {
            unset($row[$index + 1]);
            $index++;
        }
    }

    array_push($calendar, $row);
```

But since it is an associative array, I can not get the index of the loop. Is there any cleverer way to do this?

Comment: `array_keys` and use these keys as values. `array_splice` is another solution, no keys needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `foreach()`, you can use `for()` and use the duration to skip the entries you don't need.  The result is put into `$slots`.

Basically, loop over the times in the slots and if the duration is set, then increment the loop counter by the length of the appointment (duration/15 and use `ceil()` to round it up)...

```
$row = ["09:00" => (object)["duration" => 40],
    "09:15" => "",
    "09:30" => "",
    "09:45" => "",
    "10:00" => (object)["duration" => 60],
    "10:15" => "",
    "10:30" => "",
    "10:45" => "",
    "11:00" => "",
    "11:15" => "",
    "11:30" => "",
    "11:45" => (object)["duration" => 45]
];

$slots = [];
$times = array_keys($row);
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($times); $i++  )    {
    $appointment = $row[$times[$i]];
    $slots[$times[$i]] = $appointment;
    if ( $appointment->duration ?? 0 > 0 )  {
        $i += ceil($appointment->duration / 15);
    }
}
print_r($slots);
```

with the test data, this gives...

```
(
    [09:00] => stdClass Object
        (
            [duration] => 40
        )

    [10:00] => stdClass Object
        (
            [duration] => 60
        )

    [11:15] => 
    [11:30] => 
    [11:45] => stdClass Object
        (
            [duration] => 45
        )

)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. I was just changing a detail in this line: $i += ceil($appointment->duration / 15). the soluution is jumping one slot too much. If an appointment starts at 10:00 and has 45 minutes duration; the following slots should starts on 10:45. So I just substract 1 unit in the line $i += ceil($appointment->duration / 15 - 1); and the results is perfect. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Some piece of code to start with:

```
$duration = 0;
// I suggest to use array_filter and track `$duration` on each loop
$filtered = array_filter(
    $apps,
    function ($apm) use (&$duration) {
        if ($duration === 0) {
            if (!empty($apm->duration)) {
                $duration = $apm->duration - 15;
                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $duration -= 15;
            return false;    
        }
    }
);
```

Working fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/BY9u7).